# Using Polly in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

While using Polly in debug mode if exception throws, Visual Studio goes to Debug mode at first attempt. I've expected that exception will be thrown only after last attempt. Is there any way to change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: In your image the relevant code is covered. Did you use `Retry`? And even if so, how did you determine that the thrown exception popup in VS doesn't happen after the n-th try, did you put a breakpoint in before the exception gets thrown and made sure this was the first time? Also the try block in the code: does that have a catch all? If so you shouldn't see the exception popup unless you have VS configured to break on first chance exceptions (set in menu Debug->Exceptions...)

Comment: @FrankJ, Yes, there is .Retry(2) after .Handle<>. This exception will be thrown twice more after "continue" pressed. So it works, but not as I expected.

Comment: Ok if it doesn't blow up completely after the first time and goes 2 more times that means you have your VS set to 'Break on throw' for that exception type. Open up the following menu item: Debug->Exceptions... The window that opens controls which types of exceptions break on throw. However the checkboxes are not tristate, meaning only because a top level checkbox isn't checked that all of it's subitems are also unchecked, Find there the DivideByZeroException and make sure it is unchecked!

Comment: @FrankJ, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information given I suspect as stated in my comment that your VS is configured to break on throw for `DivideByZeroException`s.

In the VS Menu locate and open Debug->Exceptions...

The window that pops up controls if VS breaks on so called First Chance Exceptions for each exception type that it recognizes out of the box.

First Chance exceptions are when the exception get's thrown and before it looks if there is an appropriate handler. So even ultimately later handled exceptions will break into VS.

This is the case for all the exceptions checked in the "Thrown" column of the window.

Unfortunately the checkboxes aren't tristate, meaning even if the parent checkbox is unchecked it doesn't mean all of it's child items are unchecked as well.

You can find the exception inquestion in that window under:

Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> `System.DivideByZeroException`.

Make sure that one is unchecked.

Comment: Hmm.. that checkbox was unchecked. I unchecked "Just my code" under Debugger options, and now it works as I expected. VS not break into debugger. I've expected vice versa behavior for this option.